# dependency conflict conda create/install numpy

Tags: numpy, conda, alpine-linux, miniconda

Im trying to build a conda environment with the specific following library py36h1d66e8a_0:

```
conda create -n test numpy==1.15.1=py36h1d66e8a_0
```

result:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - numpy==1.15.1=py36h1d66e8a_0
Use "conda search <package> --info" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

even though I can install independently all of the dependencies of the package, it does not allow me to install it. How could I find what is the real dependency conflict? 
Also for context,this is running on a docker alpine container with conda 4.6.2 and it was previously running so I wonder if this could be related to a OS library package update...

Conda package dependencies:

```
numpy 1.15.1 py36h1d66e8a_0
---------------------------
file name   : numpy-1.15.1-py36h1d66e8a_0.tar.bz2
name        : numpy
version     : 1.15.1
build       : py36h1d66e8a_0
build number: 0
size        : 37 KB
license     : BSD 3-Clause
subdir      : linux-64
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64/numpy-1.15.1-py36h1d66e8a_0.tar.bz2
md5         : 2ed762dd94be9404a3161c7c76f9705f
timestamp   : 2018-08-27 21:58:49 UTC
dependencies: 
  - blas 1.0 mkl
  - libgcc-ng >=7.3.0
  - libgfortran-ng >=7,<8.0a0
  - mkl_fft >=1.0.4
  - mkl_random
  - numpy-base 1.15.1 py36h81de0dd_0
  - python >=3.6,<3.7.0a0
  - mkl >=2018.0.3,<2019.0a0
```

Example environment with all the dependencies installed:

```
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
ca-certificates           2019.1.23                     0  
certifi                   2018.11.29               py36_0  
intel-openmp              2019.1                      144  
libedit                   3.1.20181209         hc058e9b_0  
libffi                    3.2.1                hd88cf55_4  
libgcc-ng                 8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_0  
libstdcxx-ng              8.2.0                hdf63c60_1  
mkl                       2018.0.3                      1  
mkl_fft                   1.0.6            py36h7dd41cf_0  
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h4414c95_1  
ncurses                   6.1                  he6710b0_1  
numpy                     1.15.1           py36h3b04361_0  
numpy-base                1.15.1           py36h81de0dd_0  
openssl                   1.1.1b               h7b6447c_1  
pip                       19.0.3                   py36_0  
python                    3.6.7                h0371630_0  
readline                  7.0                  h7b6447c_5  
setuptools                40.8.0                   py36_0  
sqlite                    3.26.0               h7b6447c_0  
tk                        8.6.8                hbc83047_0  
wheel                     0.33.1                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.4                h14c3975_4  
zlib                      1.2.11               h7b6447c_3
```

conda install on this environment generates the same error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - numpy==1.15.1=py36h1d66e8a_0
Use "conda search <package> --info" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Answer (score 0):

you should download the required files from [Here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/numpy/files?version=1.15.1). and from the downloaded folder, give this command. you did incorrectly .

```
prml@prml-h270-gaming-4:~$ conda create -n test numpy-1.15.1-py37h1d66e8a_0.tar.bz2.
```

It will works
[see this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDFUN.png)